# Does Netty support IBM JDK?

Tags: java, netty

I was not able to find the answer by looking at Netty website.
Number of `sun.*` classes are used including `Unsafe` and `Cleaner` but those seem to be available in IBM JDK.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as we know it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is Netty meant to be build on IBM JDK? Currently it does not compile in `OpenJdkSelfSignedCertGenerator`.

Comment: no... it should be compiled by openjdk / oracle jdk. That said it should be usable with IBM JDK.